# grouping the index with the highest three values of another column using pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, series

i have a csv file that contains columns like StateName, Population, CityName... Note that for every state u can have multiple city name thus multiple population fo the same city

what i want to have is to group the StateName with the highest three population of the same city.

[what i have: (image click to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKXg7.png)

[what i want to have (image click to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWVRv.png)
my code is:

```
def answer_six():
x=census_df['STNAME'].unique()
census_df2 = df = pd.DataFrame()



for a in x :
    census_dfcopy = census_df.copy()
    census_dfcopy = census_dfcopy.set_index(['STNAME'])
    census_dfcopy  = census_dfcopy.loc[a]
    census_dfcopy = census_dfcopy.reset_index()
    census_dfcopy = census_dfcopy.set_index(['CENSUS2010POP'])
    census_dfcopy1=census_dfcopy.sort_index(ascending = False)
    census_dfcopy1= census_dfcopy1.append(census_dfcopy1)
    census_dfcopy1.groupby('STNAME')


return   census_dfcopy1.head(3)
```

answer_six()

i only get the last 3 value of the last state.

to download the csv file please visit the link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ptE6MRQ1NGrfRYBB7NKjqhOJZXlxScPo

Comment: The data is not available at the provided link.

Comment: @fuglede sorry about that the link is correct now

Comment: Someone asked the exact same question on Code Review last year: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151530/finding-the-states-with-the-three-most-populous-counties

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
census_df.groupby('STNAME').CENSUS2010POP.nlargest(3)
```

In action:

```
In [51]: df
Out[51]:
    ctyname  pop stname
0         0   10      a
1         1    9      a
2         2    1      a
3         3    3      a
4         4   12      b
5         5   12      b
6         6   13      b
7         7   14      b
8         8    4      c
9         9    3      c
10       10    2      c
11       11    1      c

In [68]: df.groupby('stname').pop.nlargest(3)
Out[68]:
stname
a       0     10
        1      9
        3      3
b       7     14
        6     13
        4     12
c       8      4
        9      3
        10     2
```

Comment: Great, if the answer was helpful, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).